# Image slider caption

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image slider which looks like this:
[image]

My codes look like this:

slick css:

```
/* Slider */
.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

slick-theme.css:

```
@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Slider */
.slick-loading .slick-list
{
    background: #fff url('./ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

/* Icons */
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('./fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('./fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}
/* Arrows */
.slick-prev,
.slick-next
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus
{
    color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover:before,
.slick-prev:focus:before,
.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
.slick-next.slick-disabled:before
{
    opacity: .25;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;

    opacity: .75;
    color: white;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev
{
    left: -25px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev
{
    right: -25px;
    left: auto;
}
.slick-prev:before
{
    content: '←';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before
{
    content: '→';
}

.slick-next
{
    right: -25px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next
{
    right: auto;
    left: -25px;
}
.slick-next:before
{
    content: '→';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before
{
    content: '←';
}

/* Dots */
.slick-slider
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;

    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;

    list-style: none;

    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li
{
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-dots li button:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 6px;
    line-height: 20px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    content: '•';
    text-align: center;

    opacity: .25;
    color: black;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before
{
    opacity: .75;
    color: black;
}
```

Then theres the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slider demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
    }

    body {
        background: #cc0099;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 80%;
        /*height: 60%;*/
        margin: 20px auto;
        background: white;
        text-align: center;
    }

    h3 {
        padding: 180px 20px;
        background: gray;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .slider div img {
        width: 100%;
        /*border: 5px solid white;*/
        /*height: auto;*/
        margin: 0;
        /*display: none;*/
        /*visibility: hidden;*/
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <div>

            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
            <!-- <img data-lazy="img/1.jpg" /> -->

        </div>

        <div>
            <!-- <img data-lazy="img/3.jpg" /> -->
            <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- <img data-lazy="img/4.jpg" /> -->
            <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- <img data-lazy="img/5.jpg" /> -->
            <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slider').slick({
            // lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
            dots: true,
            infinite: true
                // slidesToShow: 1,
                // slidesToScroll: 1,
                // adaptiveHeight: true
        });
        // $('.slider div img').css('visibility':'visible');
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried adding a p tag between one of the slides. 
Like this:

```
 <div class="slider">
            <div>
               <p>test</p>
                <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
                <!-- <img data-lazy="img/1.jpg" /> -->


            </div>
```

But i got this!:

[image]

Later i tried it in a div with a transparent background, but that didn't work either.

I just want to add a caption to a single slide, is there a way to do this without messing with the js?

Thanks in advance,

-Kevin

Comment: Hi Kevin. I would suggest recreating this in jsfiddle - it will make it easier for us to play around and help :)

Comment: I would love to but how can i do this, i have lots of files in folders. and my document is linked with those folders. @Frits

Comment: Upload only what you need to recreate the problem, we don't need the entire site, only a replication of the problem.

Comment: it might be easier to go down the ol' <figure>/<figcaption> css route?

Comment: updated fiddle - i noticed you had a white background on your slider, why? https://jsfiddle.net/y0yqau3r/

Comment: @RachelGallen Heey, this is exactly what was wrong, Don't know how I didnt see that! Will you post the answer or should i do it?

Comment: I just saw your comment after I posted my answer!

Comment: Haha, Thanks anyway! @RachelGallen

Comment: always happy to help! thx for the accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a white background on your `.slider` in your css. If you remove it, you can leave your code otherwise untouched and your `<p>` text will come up without the white background.

Should you want to overlay the text on the image, then may i suggest giving the paragraph tag a negative margin-top

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the usage, each div can have any html you'd like:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#getting-started

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("TEST");
      
        $('.slider').slick({
            // lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
            dots: true,
            infinite: true
                // slidesToShow: 1,
                // slidesToScroll: 1,
                // adaptiveHeight: true
        });
        // $('.slider div img').css('visibility':'visible');
    });
```

```css
/* Slider */
.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}

@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Slider */
.slick-loading .slick-list
{
    background: #fff url('./ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

/* Icons */
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('./fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('./fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}
/* Arrows */
.slick-prev,
.slick-next
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus
{
    color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover:before,
.slick-prev:focus:before,
.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
.slick-next.slick-disabled:before
{
    opacity: .25;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;

    opacity: .75;
    color: white;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev
{
    left: -25px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev
{
    right: -25px;
    left: auto;
}
.slick-prev:before
{
    content: '←';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before
{
    content: '→';
}

.slick-next
{
    right: -25px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next
{
    right: auto;
    left: -25px;
}
.slick-next:before
{
    content: '→';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before
{
    content: '←';
}

/* Dots */
.slick-slider
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;

    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;

    list-style: none;

    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li
{
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-dots li button:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 6px;
    line-height: 20px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    content: '•';
    text-align: center;

    opacity: .25;
    color: black;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before
{
    opacity: .75;
    color: black;
}
   * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
    }

    body {
        background: #cc0099;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 80%;
        /*height: 60%;*/
        margin: 20px auto;
        background: white;
        text-align: center;
    }

    h3 {
        padding: 180px 20px;
        background: gray;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .slider div img {
        width: 100%;
        /*border: 5px solid white;*/
        /*height: auto;*/
        margin: 0;
        /*display: none;*/
        /*visibility: hidden;*/
        display: block;
    }


.slide-text {
  background: #cc0099;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
        <div>

            <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="">
            <!-- <img data-lazy="img/1.jpg" /> -->
            <div class="slide-text">Text for slide 1</div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <!-- <img data-lazy="img/3.jpg" /> -->
            <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" alt="">
            <div class="slide-text">Text for slide 2</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- <img data-lazy="img/4.jpg" /> -->
            <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" alt="">
            <div class="slide-text">Text for slide 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: yeah, i did that in my example, but i dont want a white background on the text.

Comment: Well just use css to change that. Will edit to demonstrate.

Comment: There ya go. I added a class of ".slide-text" to the text div, but you can change it to anything. The rule for it is at the bottom of css posted, so can change that color or font style, etc to whatever you'd like.

Comment: I hoped i could make the bg transparent.

Comment: or on the image it self

Comment: You would just need an image with a transparent background then. I just used sample images from their site, but you can use any you want. Sounds like mean you want the color of the text background to match the color of the surrounding container. Take another look at it.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to leave it to the CSS to avoid bloated JS as stated [here](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/282#issuecomment-45325102).
Give it a try.

HTML:

```
<div class="slide slide--has-caption slick-slide">
  <img .../>
  <div class="slide__caption">This is my caption</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide {
  position: relative;
}

.slide__caption {
  bottom: 0;
  min-height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: did you just copy and paste the solution from the second comment from gausarts here, https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/282? If so please give authorship of the solution which you provided to the right person.

Comment: @robskrob edited the above description forgot this a long time ago